# Jenkins Build indicates build was successful but is not running the build and generating ClassCastException

Tags: jenkins

We have been running Jenkins builds successfully for over a year. Our jobs were running successfully until yesterday and there have been no changes in months to our Jenkins jobs or server.

When initiating a build from the Jenkins UI we see the attached screenshot.
[Jenkins Dashboard - Build Status UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFWZm.png)

The timing of the build is no longer displaying and the job is no longer running on the Jenkins agent.

The log file indicates there is a ClassCastException in the Jenkins cleanUpObjectStreamClassCaches operation as outlined below.

Does anyone know of a way to clear out the Jenkins cache / object stream caches?  Are there any other recommended steps to get the builds running properly again in Jenkins?

Mar 20, 2023 7:47:47 PM WARNING org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution cleanUpHeap

failed to clean up memory from Owner[01a. JobName/1:01a. JobName #1]
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.io.ObjectStreamClass$Caches$1 cannot be cast to class java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap (java.io.ObjectStreamClass$Caches$1 and java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.cleanUpObjectStreamClassCaches(CpsFlowExecution.java:1426)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.cleanUpLoader(CpsFlowExecution.java:1321)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.cleanUpHeap(CpsFlowExecution.java:1287)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:447)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:97)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:315)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:279)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
at jenkins.util.ErrorLoggingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(ErrorLoggingExecutorService.java:51)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Mar 20, 2023 7:47:47 PM INFO org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun finish
01a. JobName completed: SUCCESS

On the Jenkins server & agent we verified there is no issue with disk space - there is lots of disk space available in all server partitions.

We can manually execute the build on the Jenkins server without any issues so there is no problem with the build - it is something environmental with Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you're still stuck, but I was seeing this same behavior when I had migrated my `/var/lib/jenkins/` folder to a new host.  Somehow the `ssh-credentials` plugin had not been installed.  Manually reinstalling `ssh-credentials` seemed to resolve this.

So, maybe the takeaway is to double-check all your Jenkins plugins.